# Erasing a session and getting a new session_id() in PHP

Tags: php, session

Not sure what to do... I have this on my logout page:

```
<?php
  setcookie ("session_key", "", time() - 3600);
  session_start();
  $_SESSION = array(); 
  session_unset();
  session_destroy(); 
  header('Location:login.php');
?>
```

but still, when a new user "signs up" after logging out they get the same session id therefore causing some issues with logging in as multiple people then have the same session id.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with `session_regenerate_id(true); $_SESSION = array();` ?

It seems to do exactly what you want.